# How to pass a property into a React function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation and trying to dynamically customize the title used in my stack navigation bar by passing a string to it, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.
```

My code looks like this:

**RootComponent.js**

```
export class RootComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.loggedIn ? <SignedIn2 title={this.props.username}/> : <SignedOut />
        );
    }
}
```

**router.js:**

```
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";

export const SignedIn2 = (props) => {
    return createStackNavigator({
        SignIn: {
            screen: SignInScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: props.title
            }
        }
    });
};
```

What do I need to do to make this work? It seems I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.

Comment: @EgorEgorov It's from react-navigation...

Comment: How do you render `RootComponent`? What about `SignedOut`?

Comment: in the docs it does `const RootStack = createStackNavigator({...})` and then inside your component `return <RootStack/>`

Comment: SignedIn2 is a function so try this? `this.props.loggedIn ? SignedIn2({ title: this.props.username}) : <SignedOut />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createStackNavigator` returns a component function, not an element.

```
const SignedIn2 = (props) => createStackNavigator(..)
```

has the signature

```
SignedIn2 :: Props -> Props -> React.Element
```

Which means when you call SignedIn2 with Props you are returning a function. There's very likely a better way of doing this, but to make this work immediately you need to do something like this instead:

```
export const SignedIn2 = (props) => {
  const navigator = createStackNavigator(...)
  return React.createElement(navigator, {})
}
```

Ideally, `createStackNavigator` should only be called once. Alternatively, you could do

```
export class RootComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.loggedIn ? React.createElement(SignedIn2({ title: this.props.username })) : <SignedOut />
        );
    }
}
```

But this would be incredibly confusing.

Comment: It's important to note that rendering more than one stack navigator is a [bad idea](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html) so you should refactor your code such that you only need to render one

Comment: Why are you using `React.createElement` when the OP is using JSX? You can give your navigator a capitalized variable name and use JSX

Comment: I prefer using `React.createElement` when creating an element that is potentially unknown at runtime from the perspective of the caller (That is, I prefer using `React.createElement` when instantiating a variable, rather than naming my variables TitleCase). It's down to personal preference.